# Xuggler, going straight to a certain frame (second) without reading the whole video

Tags: java, image-processing, video-processing, xuggler, xuggle

In this example is for capturing images from a video with Xuggler, the Java video library, it's for periodically capturing frames from a video into images.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/xuggler-tutorial-frames-capture-video.html

In it I see that we’re creating a media reader and reading the video until the time we capture the image.
can this process be speeded up, for example by jumping to a certain frame, without having to read all the frames? starting to only “play” the video near the capture time?
Does Xuggler support that (jumping to a certain certain frame at a certain second?)

```
package com.javacodegeeks.xuggler;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaListenerAdapter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.event.IVideoPictureEvent;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;


public class VideoThumbnailsExample {

    public static final double SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 10;

    private static final String inputFilename = "c:/Java_is_Everywhere.mp4";
    private static final String outputFilePrefix = "c:/snapshots/mysnapshot";

    // The video stream index, used to ensure we display frames from one and
    // only one video stream from the media container.
    private static int mVideoStreamIndex = -1;

    // Time of last frame write
    private static long mLastPtsWrite = Global.NO_PTS;

    public static final long MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 
        (long)(Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);

        // stipulate that we want BufferedImages created in BGR 24bit color space
        mediaReader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

        mediaReader.addListener(new ImageSnapListener());

        // read out the contents of the media file and
        // dispatch events to the attached listener
        while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null) ;

    }

    private static class ImageSnapListener extends MediaListenerAdapter {

        public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {

            if (event.getStreamIndex() != mVideoStreamIndex) {
                // if the selected video stream id is not yet set, go ahead an
                // select this lucky video stream
                if (mVideoStreamIndex == -1)
                    mVideoStreamIndex = event.getStreamIndex();
                // no need to show frames from this video stream
                else
                    return;
            }

            // if uninitialized, back date mLastPtsWrite to get the very first frame
            if (mLastPtsWrite == Global.NO_PTS)
                mLastPtsWrite = event.getTimeStamp() - MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;

            // if it's time to write the next frame
            if (event.getTimeStamp() - mLastPtsWrite >= 
                    MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES) {

                String outputFilename = dumpImageToFile(event.getImage());

                // indicate file written
                double seconds = ((double) event.getTimeStamp()) / 
                    Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND;
                System.out.printf(
                        "at elapsed time of %6.3f seconds wrote: %s\n",
                        seconds, outputFilename);

                // update last write time
                mLastPtsWrite += MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;
            }

        }

        private String dumpImageToFile(BufferedImage image) {
            try {
                String outputFilename = outputFilePrefix + 
                     System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(outputFilename));
                return outputFilename;
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure - since they are based on ffmpeg they should so look in the doc - finally I think you should try ffmpeg straight - after your unsuccessful attempt with video google as well

Comment: @gpasch It's being added to a java application, hence I'm using Xuggler. What command in  ffmpeg that goes straight to a a particular second in a video capture an image of that frame? does it also involve a mediaReader?

Comment: no it's command line so you have to invoke it through the runtime - if you know the frame rate and duration you maybe even extract frame n, but to go to second n it's easy. See ffmpeg